# Why aren't balloon tips shown pointing at the correct control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, tooltip

I am using a `ToolTip` control on my form, but have discovered that even though my cursor is on one control, the tooltip is showing somewhere else. I would like to show this within the control my cursor is on.

[image]

As shown in the image above, when my cursor is over `Textbox3`, the tooltip is showing on `Textbox4`. I would like for it to be displayed pointing at `Textbox3`.

I'm currently using the following code to display the tooltip in 3 different events:

```
 private void txtImmediateddest_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ttpDetail.Show("Ex:111000025", txtImmediateddest);
 }

 private void txtImmediateddest_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ttpDetail.Show("Ex:111000025", txtImmediateddest);
 }

  private void txtImmediateddest_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
      ttpDetail.Show("Ex:111000025", txtImmediateddest, e.Location);
      //toolTipimmeddest.Show("Required & Must be 9 Digits", txtImmediateddest);
  }
```

Edit

```
 private void textBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ttpDetail.AutoPopDelay = 2000;
        ttpDetail.InitialDelay = 1000;
        ttpDetail.ReshowDelay = 500;
        ttpDetail.IsBalloon = true;
        //ttpDetail.SetToolTip(textBox1, "Ex:01(Should be Numeric)");
        ttpDetail.Show("Ex : 01(Should Be Numeric)", textBox1,textBox1.Width, textBox1.Height/10,5000);
    }
```

This works fine but when the mouse initially on to the control it is displaying the normal if i had for second time it is displaying correctly

Look at the following images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is because your `ToolTip` control's [`IsBalloon` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.isballoon.aspx) is set to "True". With this property set, the `ToolTip` doesn't change its relative location, causing the balloon's arrow to point to the wrong control.

Here's a side-by-side comparison demonstrating this phenomenon:

[image]      [image]

The simple fix, obviously, is to disable the `IsBalloon` property by setting it to "False". The control will revert to displaying a standard, rectangular tooltip window, which will look correctly aligned.

If that's not acceptable to you, then you will have to specify the exact location where you want the tooltip balloon to appear. Unfortunately, it looks like there's a bug in the `ToolTip` control that causes it not to appear properly the first time it is attached to a control. This can generally be fixed by calling the `Show` method with an empty string once. For example, using the following code:

```
private void txtImmediateddest_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ttpDetail.Show(string.Empty, textBox3, 0);
    ttpDetail.Show("Ex:111000025", textBox3, textBox3.Width / 2, textBox3.Height, 5000);
}
```

produces this result:

[image]

Of course, your luck may vary going this route, as well. I generally don't use the built-in `ToolTip` control for edit controls (such as textboxes and comboboxes). I find it's much more reliable to P/Invoke [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950.aspx), specifying [`EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761668.aspx) and an [`EDITBALLOONTIP` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775466.aspx) containing information about the tooltip that I want to show. I'll leave looking up the appropriate definitions and writing the wrapper code as an exercise for the reader, as this answer is much too long already.

Comment: This is displaying a black color tooltip instead of the message and also the balloon tip is also not getting displayed

Comment: @Dorababu: "This" doesn't tell me much. There were 3 different possible workarounds in my answer: which one did you try? Also, I know they all work because I tested them myself to take the screenshots. Can you update your question with the code you're using for comparison purposes?

Comment: @ Cody Gray I just used the code of your's and also set isBallon to false

Comment: @Dorababu: You don't have to set `IsBalloon` to false if you're using the second code snippet. But I have no idea why it isn't working for you. I wrote and tested this on Server 2008 R2, and then tested it again (to take the screenshots) on a Windows XP VM. Everything was solid in both environments. There must be a problem in the code you've added, or elsewhere in your project.

Comment: Hey small help i need the same fashioned to be worked on MouseHover of a particular Textbox can you post

Comment: @Dorababu: If what I suggested above isn't working for that event, I have no idea. Like I said, the WinForms `ToolTip` control is not without it's problems. Try Jie Wang's solution posted in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/7fe50cfa-885e-4e2f-bbba-55c0b42d852b/). I can't figure out a way to direct link to a specific post, but it's about half-way down, where the code is provided for a `BalloonTipTextBox` class. Look for the screenshots just below the code—the result is even prettier than the one you get from WinForms. It has actual anti-aliasing.

Comment: That one also for Enter but i need it to be on Mousehover or mouse click

Comment: @ Cody Gray can you check my edits and please let me know what to do

Comment: @Dorababu: The edits to your question indicate that the tooltip works correctly the second time you show it. I discussed this above in my answer: "Unfortunately, it looks like there's a bug in the ToolTip control that causes it not to appear properly the first time it is attached to a control. This can generally be fixed by calling the Show method with an empty string once." The code you've shown in the edit doesn't call the `Show` method twice. See if that doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: If i show for twice it is displaying as in the First Image only

Comment: This approach will not work in my case.Should try to show with the same position offset as the second call in the first call.

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of troubleshooting I found the code bellow to be net superior to the build-in balloon ToolTip. Make sure Visual Styles are enabled by uncommenting the dependency in the manifest file.

Create a BalloonTip over a TextBox like this:

```
new BalloonTip("Title", "Message", textBox1, BalloonTip.ICON.INFO, 5000);
```

and implement `BalloonTip` like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Lib.Windows
{
    class BalloonTip
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        private IntPtr hWnd;

        public BalloonTip(string text, Control control)
        {
            Show("", text, control);
        }

        public BalloonTip(string title, string text, Control control, ICON icon = 0, double timeOut = 0, bool focus = false)
        {
            Show(title, text, control, icon, timeOut, focus);
        }

        void Show(string title, string text, Control control, ICON icon = 0, double timeOut = 0, bool focus = false, short x = 0, short y = 0)
        {
            if (x == 0 && y == 0)
            {
                x = (short)(control.RectangleToScreen(control.ClientRectangle).Left + control.Width / 2);
                y = (short)(control.RectangleToScreen(control.ClientRectangle).Top + control.Height / 2);
            }
            TOOLINFO toolInfo = new TOOLINFO();
            toolInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(toolInfo);
            toolInfo.uFlags = 0x20; // TTF_TRACK
            toolInfo.lpszText = text;
            IntPtr pToolInfo = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(toolInfo));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(toolInfo, pToolInfo, false);
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(title);
            buffer = buffer.Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray();
            IntPtr pszTitle = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(buffer.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, pszTitle, buffer.Length);
            hWnd = User32.CreateWindowEx(0x8, "tooltips_class32", "", 0xC3, 0, 0, 0, 0, control.Parent.Handle, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1028, (IntPtr)0, pToolInfo); // TTM_ADDTOOL
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1042, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)((ushort)x | ((ushort)y << 16))); // TTM_TRACKPOSITION
            //User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1043, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0); // TTM_SETTIPBKCOLOR
            //User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1044, (IntPtr)0xffff, (IntPtr)0); // TTM_SETTIPTEXTCOLOR
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1056, (IntPtr)icon, pszTitle); // TTM_SETTITLE 0:None, 1:Info, 2:Warning, 3:Error, >3:assumed to be an hIcon. ; 1057 for Unicode
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1048, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)500); // TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x40c, (IntPtr)0, pToolInfo); // TTM_UPDATETIPTEXT; 0x439 for Unicode
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1041, (IntPtr)1, pToolInfo); // TTM_TRACKACTIVATE
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pszTitle);
            Marshal.DestroyStructure(pToolInfo, typeof(TOOLINFO));
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pToolInfo);
            if (focus)
                control.Focus();
            // uncomment bellow to make balloon close when user changes focus,
            // starts typing, resizes/moves parent window, minimizes parent window, etc
            // adjust which control events to subscribe to depending on the control over which the balloon tip is shown

            /*control.Click += control_Event;
            control.Leave += control_Event;
            control.TextChanged += control_Event;
            control.LocationChanged += control_Event;
            control.SizeChanged += control_Event;
            control.VisibleChanged += control_Event;
            Control parent = control.Parent;
            while(parent != null)
            {
                parent.VisibleChanged += control_Event;
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }
            control.TopLevelControl.LocationChanged += control_Event;
            ((Form)control.TopLevelControl).Deactivate += control_Event;*/

            timer.AutoReset = false;
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
            if (timeOut > 0)
            {
                timer.Interval = timeOut;
                timer.Start();
            }
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        void control_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        void Close()
        {
            if (!semaphore.Wait(0)) // ensures one time only execution
                return;
            timer.Elapsed -= timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Close();
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0010, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0); // WM_CLOSE
            //User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0002, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0); // WM_DESTROY
            //User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0082, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0); // WM_NCDESTROY
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct TOOLINFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public uint uFlags;
            public IntPtr hwnd;
            public IntPtr uId;
            public RECT rect;
            public IntPtr hinst;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string lpszText;
            public IntPtr lParam;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        public enum ICON
        {
            NONE,
            INFO,
            WARNING,
            ERROR
        }
    }

    static class User32
    {
        [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(uint dwExStyle, string lpClassName, string lpWindowName, uint dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hWndParent, IntPtr hMenu, IntPtr hInstance, IntPtr LPVOIDlpParam);
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: @miroxlav `x` and `y` are calculated at the beginning of Show() method based on control's coordinates. They are screen coordinates (not relative to the top left corner of the window) and are set by sending a windows message `TTM_TRACKPOSITION`. Break on `x` and `y` and make sure are valid screen coordinates in pixels. I have no idea why the coordinates would fail. I assume it has to do something with the conversion from client to screen coordinates. You could add `x` and `y` as function parameters for Show() method. Make them `short` instead of `ushort` so it works with multimonitors.

Comment: Where do you get that `SemaphoreSlim` class?

Comment: Ah. 4.5. Managed to use just Semaphore. I'm curious though... how can you make it close on clicking the actual tooltip?

Comment: My upvote for this. Best code for tooltip, It beats out regular tooltip for sure. Thanks Chris !

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use only the **SetToolTip** method (with out calling the **show** method) in the **MouseOver** event

**ttpTemp.SetToolTip(txtTemp, "Ex:01(Should be Numeric)");**

This works fine for me (I use Managed C++ but I think it is the same).

Answer (score 1):

With credits to [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30054010/2392157), I post VB.NET port here:

```vb
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace [Lib].Windows
    Class BalloonTip
        Private timer As New System.Timers.Timer()
        Private semaphore As New System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(1)
        Private hWnd As IntPtr

        Public Sub New(text As String, control As Control)
            Show("", text, control)
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(title As String, text As String, control As Control, Optional icon As ICON = 0, Optional timeOut As Double = 0, Optional focus As Boolean = False)
            Show(title, text, control, icon, timeOut, focus)
        End Sub

        Private Sub Show(title As String, text As String, control As Control, Optional icon As ICON = 0, Optional timeout As Double = 0, Optional focus As Boolean = False)
            Dim x As UShort = CType(control.RectangleToScreen(control.ClientRectangle).Left + control.Width / 2, UShort)
            Dim y As UShort = CType(control.RectangleToScreen(control.ClientRectangle).Top + control.Height / 2, UShort)
            Dim toolInfo As New TOOLINFO()
            toolInfo.cbSize = CType(Marshal.SizeOf(toolInfo), UInteger)
            toolInfo.uFlags = &H20
            ' TTF_TRACK
            toolInfo.lpszText = text
            Dim pToolInfo As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(toolInfo))
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(toolInfo, pToolInfo, False)
            Dim buffer As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(title)
            buffer = buffer.Concat(New Byte() {0}).ToArray()
            Dim pszTitle As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(buffer.Length)
            Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, pszTitle, buffer.Length)
            hWnd = User32.CreateWindowEx(&H8, "tooltips_class32", "", &HC3, 0, 0, _
                0, 0, control.Parent.Handle, CType(0, IntPtr), CType(0, IntPtr), CType(0, IntPtr))
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1028, CType(0, IntPtr), pToolInfo)
            ' TTM_ADDTOOL
            'User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1043, CType(0, IntPtr), CType(0, IntPtr); ' TTM_SETTIPBKCOLOR
            'User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1044, CType(&HFFFF, IntPtr), CType(0, IntPtr); ' TTM_SETTIPTEXTCOLOR
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1056, CType(icon, IntPtr), pszTitle)
            ' TTM_SETTITLE 0:None, 1:Info, 2:Warning, 3:Error, >3:assumed to be an hIcon. ; 1057 for Unicode
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1048, CType(0, IntPtr), CType(500, IntPtr))
            ' TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, &H40C, CType(0, IntPtr), pToolInfo)
            ' TTM_UPDATETIPTEXT; 0x439 for Unicode
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1042, CType(0, IntPtr), CType(x Or (CUInt(y) << 16), IntPtr))
            ' TTM_TRACKPOSITION
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, 1041, CType(1, IntPtr), pToolInfo)
            ' TTM_TRACKACTIVATE
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pszTitle)
            Marshal.DestroyStructure(pToolInfo, GetType(TOOLINFO))
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pToolInfo)
            If focus Then
                control.Focus()
            End If

            ' uncomment below to make balloon close when user changes focus,
            ' starts typing, resizes/moves parent window, minimizes parent window, etc
            ' adjust which control events to subscribe to depending on the control over which the balloon tip is shown
            'AddHandler control.Click, AddressOf control_Event
            'AddHandler control.Leave, AddressOf control_Event
            'AddHandler control.TextChanged, AddressOf control_Event
            'AddHandler control.LocationChanged, AddressOf control_Event
            'AddHandler control.SizeChanged, AddressOf control_Event
            'AddHandler control.VisibleChanged, AddressOf control_Event
            'Dim parent As Control = control.Parent
            'While Not (parent Is Nothing)
            '    AddHandler parent.VisibleChanged, AddressOf control_Event
            '    parent = parent.Parent
            'End While
            'AddHandler control.TopLevelControl.LocationChanged, AddressOf control_Event
            'AddHandler DirectCast(control.TopLevelControl, Form).Deactivate, AddressOf control_Event
            timer.AutoReset = False
            RemoveHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf timer_Elapsed
            If timeout > 0 Then
                timer.Interval = timeout
                timer.Start()
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub timer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
            Close()
        End Sub

        Private Sub control_Event(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            Close()
        End Sub

        Sub Close()
            If Not semaphore.Wait(0) Then
                ' ensures one time only execution
                Return
            End If
            RemoveHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf timer_Elapsed
            timer.Close()
            User32.SendMessage(hWnd, &H10, CType(0, IntPtr), CType(0, IntPtr))
            ' WM_CLOSE
            'User32.SendMessage(hWnd, &H0002, CType(0, IntPtr), CType(0, IntPtr)); ' WM_DESTROY
            'User32.SendMessage(hWnd, &H0082, CType(0, IntPtr), CType(0, IntPtr)); ' WM_NCDESTROY
        End Sub

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
        Private Structure TOOLINFO
            Public cbSize As UInteger
            Public uFlags As UInteger
            Public hwnd As IntPtr
            Public uId As IntPtr
            Public rect As RECT
            Public hinst As IntPtr
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)> _
            Public lpszText As String
            Public lParam As IntPtr
        End Structure
        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
        Private Structure RECT
            Public Left As Integer
            Public Top As Integer
            Public Right As Integer
            Public Bottom As Integer
        End Structure

        Public Enum ICON
            NONE
            INFO
            WARNING
            [ERROR]
        End Enum
    End Class

    NotInheritable Class User32
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub
        <DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")> _
        Public Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, Msg As UInt32, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
        End Function
        <DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")> _
        Public Shared Function CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle As UInteger, lpClassName As String, lpWindowName As String, dwStyle As UInteger, x As Integer, y As Integer, _
            nWidth As Integer, nHeight As Integer, hWndParent As IntPtr, hMenu As IntPtr, hInstance As IntPtr, LPVOIDlpParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: And we use it like this: `Dim btt As New [Lib].Windows.BalloonTip("Title", "Message", sender, [Lib].Windows.BalloonTip.ICON.INFO, 5000)`

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got at last by this code

When MouseLeave

```
       public class MouseLeave
    {
        public void mouseLeave(TextBox txtTemp, ToolTip ttpTemp)
        {
            ttpTemp.Hide(txtTemp);
        }
    }
```

When Mouse Over

```
    public class MouseOver
    {
        public void mouseOver(TextBox txtTemp, ToolTip ttpTemp)
        {
            switch (txtTemp.Name)
            {
                case "textBox1":
                    {

                        ttpTemp.AutoPopDelay = 2000;
                        ttpTemp.InitialDelay = 1000;
                        ttpTemp.ReshowDelay = 500;
                        ttpTemp.IsBalloon = true;
                        ttpTemp.SetToolTip(txtTemp, "Ex:01(Should be Numeric)");
                        ttpTemp.Show("Ex : 01(Should Be Numeric)", txtTemp, txtTemp.Width, txtTemp.Height / 10, 5000);
                    }
                    break;

                case "txtDetail":
                    {

                        ttpTemp.AutoPopDelay = 2000;
                        ttpTemp.InitialDelay = 1000;
                        ttpTemp.ReshowDelay = 500;
                        ttpTemp.IsBalloon = true;
                        ttpTemp.SetToolTip(txtTemp, "Ex:01(Should be Numeric)");
                        ttpTemp.Show("Ex : 01(Should Be Numeric)", txtTemp, txtTemp.Width, txtTemp.Height / 10, 5000);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```