# Display Tooltip over cursor in textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, tooltip

I am working on a project in Winforms (.NET Framework 4.7.2), and would like to display a bubble tooltip over the cursor in a textbox control. This is what I currently have:

[image: What I currently have]

And this is what I would like:

[image: What I would like]

I have tried both `SetToolTip()` and `Tooltip.Show()` methods, but I cannot make the tooltip display over the textbox cursor. **How do I accomplish this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the cursor (caret) position using the win32 function [`GetCaretPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcaretpos) and then pass that position to the `ToolTip.Show()` method.

First, add the following to your class ([preferably, a separate *static* class for native methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1060-move-p-invokes-to-nativemethods-class)):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetCaretPos(out Point lpPoint);
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
ToolTip tTip = new ToolTip();
tTip.IsBalloon = true;
tTip.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
tTip.ToolTipTitle = "Your title";

Point p;
if (GetCaretPos(out p))
{
    // This is optional. Removing it causes the arrow to point at the top of the line.
    int yOffset = textBox1.Font.Height;
    p.Y += yOffset;

    // Calling .Show() two times because of a known bug in the ToolTip control.
    // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4646021/4934172
    tTip.Show(string.Empty, textBox1, 0);
    tTip.Show("Your message here", textBox1, p, 1000);
}
```

**Note:**

I called the `ToolTip.Show()` method twice, the first time with an empty string and a duration of 0 ms because of a known bug in the ToolTip control which causes the balloon arrow not to point to the right place the first time it's called. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4646021/4934172) for more info.

Comment: You could avoid PInvoking with `Point p = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart);`. The text baseline position (in `tTip.Show()`) could then be `new Point(p.X, p.Y + textBox1.Font.Height)`. As a note, if you set `tTip.SetToolTip(textBox1, " ");`, before `tTip.IsBalloon = true;`, it will show up correctly. But of course you need two lines of code anyway.

Comment: @Jimi Actually, `GetPositionFromCharIndex()` will return `(0, 0)` if the caret is after the last character. You'll have to do [some tweaking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1831339/4934172) to make it work, and even more tweaking to make it _accurately_ point to the caret position (might not be crucial here). Another option too is to measure the string until `SelectionStart`, but then `GetCaretPos()` works out of the box, so I would stick with it unless the slight change in performance is _really_ an issue.

Comment: You could re-calculate `p.X` this way: `Point p = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart - 1);` `p.X += (p.X > 0) ? (p.X / (textBox1.SelectionStart - textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine())) : 0;`. Could be useful if PInvoking is not an option in some scenario. Otherwise, `GetCaretPos()` is good.

Comment: Almost; it works perfectly if the mouse is not over the control.. but if the tooltip gets called while the mouse is on the textbox, it gets shown over the textbox. I guess I should check whether or not the mouse is on the textbox and don't do anything to the caret position if the mouse is on the control? Or is there a more effective way? Thanks.